# How to convert Foreign Key Field into Many To Many Field without disturbing existing data in the database?

Tags: mysql, django

My code snippet is as follows :

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
```

Consider both the table has data in the database. What is the possible way to convert the `Foreign Key Field(in Table2)` into `Many To Many` Field without losing existing data in the database?

```
*Note: I am using Django 1.6.4(not using Django migrations)*
```

Comment: You are in for a lot of hard work. Why are you using this unsupported version. upgrade to 1.8 or 1.10 and make use of migrations.

Comment: @e4c5 Upgrading version is often quite painful.  The project he mentioned may not be in active maintainance

Comment: Still if it's online it should be upgraded because django 1.6 is unmaintained and you may get security issues. Changing tables via migrations is a lot easier than changing tables manually

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in a couple of steps. First add the M2M-field and copy your data. Next change your application logic to use the new field. Finally you can remove the old ForeignKey-field.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
    table1_new = models.ManyToManyField(Table1, related_name='_')

# python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py shell
# get things done by a for loop


class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    table1_new = models.ManyToManyField(Table1, related_name='_')

# python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate


class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    table1 = models.ManyToManyField(Table1)

# python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: you are saying don't upgrade to 1.8 but you are giving a solution that uses migrations!!

Comment: I think south will solve his problem of not having migrations.   Not so much sure about it since I haven't used older versions.